# Error after removing sql server 2008 R2 Express edition and instaling Entreprise edition: Unable to connect to WIN7 \ MSSQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm having this issue after installing MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition, I'm getting this message error:

```
Unable to connect to WIN7 \ MSSQLSERVER
A network-related error or instance-specific occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces , error : 25 - Connection string is not valid ) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)
```

NB: Before installing this version i did remove an existing MSSQL 2008 R2 EXPRESS, but after launching "SQL Server Management Studio" i strangely got for the first time the following instance of the express edition version:
WIN7 \ SQLEXPRESS

My configs are:
Windows 7 Enterprise Edition
SQL SERVER 2008  R2 Enterprise

the SQL connection session:
 - DB Engine
 - WIN7 \ MSSQLSERVER
 - Windows Authentication

Please HELP !!

Comment: So basically you consider "not knowing how to set up a server system" a programming question?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm here to make my code work, and resolving this issue is the first step to that, anyway i should of post it in the Database admin site, thank you )

Comment: Sorry, with this excuse you can also ask us what pizza tastes best, because you need to eat before programmign. THis is not a programming question but a "how do I set up this server software, as I haven o clue how the firewall works, how sql server network configuration works". And these questions are not programming specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve created a second instance, it did work, then I’ve tested to connect with my PC name only it did work; So for the default instance we only specify the computer name  :)

Following the advice of  Tom Tom (Tanks to him) I asked for this in the DATABASE ADMIN web site and got the right answer for it, this is the link:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82387/error-after-removing-sql-server-2008-r2-express-edition-and-instaling-entreprise